# How to display particular range values in varchar column in SQL SERVER 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

My table Name is 'information'

Structure is:

```
No int,
Name varchar(200),
Date varchar(30)
```

Records:

```
No  Name        Date
=====================================
1   A       25/08/2012
2   B       10/08/2012
3   C       11/08/2012
4   D       01/09/2012
```

My Problem is i want the No,Name,Date for between 25/08/2012 to 01/09/2012

i was tried the follwing query, but i am unable to get it.

```
select No,Name,Date 
from information 
where Date>='25/08/2012' and Date<='01/09/2012'
```

I don't want to alter the date column(varchar) to datetime

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below query you do not need to alter your Date column(varchar) to datetime.

```
select No,Name,Date from information where CONVERT(date,[DATE],103) >=  CONVERT(date,'25/08/2012',103)  and CONVERT(date,[DATE],103) <=  CONVERT(date,'01/09/2012',103)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please update as CONVERT(datetime,[DATE],103) insetad of CONVERT(date,[DATE],103)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to convert varchar to datetime:

```
SELECT No,Name,Date from information 
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, Date, 103) >= CONVERT(datetime, '25/08/2012', 103) 
AND CONVERT(datetime, Date, 103) <= CONVERT(datetime, '01/09/2012', 103)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please update the last line as <= instead of >=

Answer (score 1):

As said before, convert your column to a datetime. I'd personally use a between statement as its cleaner.

```
select No,Name,Date from information where convert(datetime, Date, 103) between convert(datetime, '25/08/2012', 103) and convert(datetime, '01/09/2012', 103)
```

depending on your input parameters you might be able to convert them into datetime beforehand (so you can check the values entered before they are executed. Example;

```
declare @startdate datetime
declare @enddate datetime

set @startdate = convert(datetime, '25/08/2012', 103)
set @enddate = convert(datetime, '01/09/2012', 103)

select No,Name,Date from information where convert(datetime, Date, 103) between @stardate and @enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `VARCHAR` datatype to `Date`. Try,

```
SELECT  No, Name, [Date]
FROM    information 
where   CAST([Date] AS Date) BETWEEN CAST('2012-08-25' AS DATE) AND  
                                     CAST('2012-09-09' AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was tried your query but i am unable to get it. Initally the error was 'Type Date is not a defined system type'. after i was changed 'as Date' to 'as Datetime', the error was 'The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.'